# PHPStorm visible files when developing a task

Tags: editor, phpstorm

i'm veeeeeeeery tired to have to find a file every time i have to edit it. I detected that when i'm developing a task with a concrete conceptual scope i always use the same files... but i have to search for them betwen all files in the project, thats an important waste of time i'd love to save. For example i use kanbanery for task managing, every task has an associated number , #93859 for example, it would be GREAT to start a file tree view with only the asociated files of that task visible. Maybe is already there something like that.. in that case i'd love to know it! Or for example if i use GIT , it would be great to have rapidly visible the files i touched previously in the branch i am at that moment.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't really know if it will help you but PHPStorm has great thing - Navigate->File... Type part of file name - and be happy. Map that finder for example to Ctrl+q to have fast access.
2. There are bookmarks in Navigate menu, maybe you can use them.
3. And finally there is Favourites panel among the panels on left side
   Make your choice! =)

Comment: thanks for the tip! though sometimes there are lot of files with the same name, but other times will be great